# Is it possible to run doctests using unit2

Tags: python, testing, nose, unittest2

I recently switched from nose to the new unittest2 package for my python unit testing needs. It does everything I want, except from the fact that I can't get its "discover" command to recognize the doctests in my code - I still have to use nose to run them. Is this not implemented or is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unit2 only discovers regular Python tests. In order to have it run your doctests, I'm afraid you would need to write some minimal boilerplate. Also: the upcoming plugin architecture will  make it easy to automate some of these tasks.

In the meantime. you might want to take a look at tox (described here by unittest2 creator) http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/weblog/arch_d7_2010_07_10.shtml

Comment: Thanks. Tox is really interesting. And as we are using sphinx to build documentation, using that to run doctests seems fine, too :)

Answer (score 1):

The boilerplate needed to tell unit2 about your doctests is actually given in the current doctest documentation, though it took me a few minutes to find it:

http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html#unittest-api

Note that you can pass module names to the `DocTestSuite` constructor instead of having to import the module yourself, which can cut the length of your boilerplate file in half; it just needs to look like:

```
from doctest import DocTestSuite
from unittest import TestSuite

def load_tests(loader, tests, pattern):
    suite = TestSuite()
    suite.addTests(DocTestSuite('my.module.one'))
    suite.addTests(DocTestSuite('my.module.two'))
    suite.addTests(DocTestSuite('my.module.three'))
    return suite
```